# How to get Jenkins credential description text without script approval?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Is there any way to get a Jenkins credential description without adding script approvals?

I looked in the credential plugin documentation/code but only saw usernameVariable/passwordVariable (no descriptionVariable or similar).

I found some groovy scripting that works but it requires 4 scripts approvals (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Printing+a+list+of+credentials+and+their+IDs) -

```
script {
    def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
        com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernameCredentials.class,
        Jenkins.instance,
        null,
        null
    )
    for (c in creds) {
        echo c.id
        echo c.description
    }
}
```

This needs the following script approvals, where the credential plugin doesn't require any script approvals.

```
method com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.IdCredentials getId
method com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardCredentials getDescription
staticMethod com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider lookupCredentials java.lang.Class hudson.model.ItemGroup org.acegisecurity.Authentication java.util.List
staticMethod jenkins.model.Jenkins getInstance
```

Is there any way to get a credential description without approvals or would a credential plugin feature request be the best option? (haven't checked if one exists already yet)